# why sql server change tracking seems not recording some changes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We enabled row level change tracking on all tables in one of our databases and are trying identify when new data is coming to perform an automation routine.

However, what we found is that only some data is reporting changes. For example, the following query will return no records. But we can clearly see that the data was changed in the database some time ago.

```
SELECT CT.*
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [dbo].[LuUnitRating], NULL) AS CT
WHERE CT.CitiCode = 'q9zs';
```

Does anyone see similar issues? Is there a way to debug this?
Could it be that there is too much data updated and somehow the change was removed?

Comment: It's right there when you first start looking at [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15): "Only the fact that a row has changed is required, not how many times the row has changed or the values of any intermediate changes." and a further note highlighting you may be looking for CDC if you need all changes.

Comment: sorry, @Damien_The_Unbeliever, what you mean? my query gives no record, does it mean it never changed? As certainly the data is different now.  I don't need to know how many time it changed, just need to be sure when changes happen, it will be reported.

Comment: It probably means the record has not changed _since Change Tracking was enabled on the table_. Neither Change Tracking nor Change Data Capture can tell you about changes that occurred in the past before they were enabled.

Comment: What is the configured retention period and the auto_cleanup setting? (see sys.change_tracking_databases)

Comment: 2 days with auto_cleanup on. Think it is the default @RazvanSocol